# How to insert new element using sibling element values with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file and need to add a new element that contains values from a sibling element with XSLT. What I have is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
<record>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">(OCoLC)ocm02255682</subfield>
        </datafield>
      <datafield tag="959" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
         <subfield code="a">(MILdb)299946</subfield>
      </datafield>
        <datafield tag="959" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">(UIUdb)3899758</subfield>
        </datafield>
</record>
```

And what I need is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<collection
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
<record>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">(OCoLC)ocm02255682</subfield>
        </datafield>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="z">(UIU)Voyager3899758</subfield>
        </datafield>
      <datafield tag="959" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
         <subfield code="a">(MILdb)299946</subfield>
      </datafield>
        <datafield tag="959" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="a">(UIUdb)3899758</subfield>
        </datafield>
</record>
```

I've been working at it for a few hours with no meaningful output. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what I have so far. This is the first XSLT I've tried to write, and I not sure if I'm on the right track. The output has the new field (but with namespaces for some reason), and does not include the value from the 959 subfield a element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="marc:record">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
                <subfield code="z">(UIU)Voyager
                     <xsl:value-of select="marc:datafield[@tag=959]/marc:subfield[@code='a']"/>
                </subfield>
            </datafield>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
                
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Could you add whatever xsl you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
exclude-result-prefixes="marc">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="marc:record">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
            <subfield code="z">
                <xsl:text>(UIU)Voyager</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(marc:datafield[@tag=959]/marc:subfield[@code='a'], ')')"/>
            </subfield>
        </datafield>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

To create the new element only when a `datafield` whose `tag` value is `959` and has a `subfield` that starts with `"(UIUdb)"` exists, change the 2nd template to:

```
<xsl:template match="marc:datafield[@tag=959][starts-with(marc:subfield, '(UIUdb)')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
        <subfield code="z">
            <xsl:text>(UIU)Voyager</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(marc:subfield, '(UIUdb)')"/>
        </subfield>
    </datafield>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it! The new datafield element still has the marc namespace, but I can edit that out easily enough.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"new datafield element still has the marc namespace"*. **All** `datafield` elements are in the same namespace. There should be no need to edit anything out - see the demo here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzt4

Comment: It gives me <datafield xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim" tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" "> where I was expecting <datafield tag="035" ind1=" " ind2=" ">. I don't think it affects anything, but none of the other datafields have that within the element tag.

Comment: Are you using the exact stylesheet I have posted, with the `exclude-result-prefixes="marc"` atttribute?

Comment: Yep. I edited it to make it conditional (I only want the new datafield element if there is a 959 datafield in the record, otherwise I just want the record as is), but I was still getting the namespace repeated in the new element with exactly what you posted.

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I used Saxon6.5.5 in Oxygen. I just tried Xalan, Saxon-HE 9.8.0.12, Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12, and Saxon-EE 9.8.0.12 and got similar output.

Comment: There must be some difference. You can see that Saxon 9.8 does NOT return the result you claim: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmCzt4/1

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am not going to turn this into a series. Post a new question with your new requirement.